# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in angular

Tags: angularjs

Here is my controller the error is cannot read property then of undefined. It console logs the $scope.newCat and then breaks down. I've been at this for a while and can't figure it out.

==================================================================================

```
app.controller('CatCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Cat) {
   $scope.cats = Cat.all;

  $scope.newCat = {note: '', 'title': ''};

   $scope.submitCat = function () {
      console.log($scope.newCat);
      Cat.create($scope.newCat).then(function (ref) {

        $scope.newCat = {note: '', title: '', date: ''};
      });
    };

  $scope.deleteCat = function (catId) {
     Cat.delete(catId);
  };

});
```

==================================================================================

## here is my service

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Cat',
  function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, User) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'cats');

    var cats = $firebase(ref);

    var Cat = {
      all: cats,
      create: function (cat) {
        if (User.signedIn()) {
          var user = User.getCurrent();

          cat.owner = user.username;


          return cats.$add(cat).then(function (ref) {
            var catId = ref.name();

            user.$child('cats').$child(catId).$set(catId);

            return catId;
          });
        }
      },
      find: function (catId) {
        return cats.$child(moodId);
      },
      delete: function (catId) {
        if (User.signedIn()) {
          var cat = Cat.find(catId);

          cat.$on('loaded', function () {
            var user = User.findByUsername(cat.owner);

            cats.$remove(catId).then(function () {
              user.$child('cats').$remove(catId);
            });
          });
        }
      }
    };

    return Cat;
  });
```

Comment: Can you please provide the Cat-Service :) you're using?

Comment: yeah what is in Cat?

Comment: I'm just kind of new to this, so I'm trying to work through the api documentation, I feel like it's almost right and I'm close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the create method, one possibility where it will return `undefined` is if you are not logged in, if `User.signedIn()` is `false`. Are you sure you're logged in, otherwise that will explain the issue.

Comment: I had a registration page but not a login, can't believe I didn't see that! Thank You!